# Phonon not functionning with some mp3s

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, mp3, phonon

I'm trying to make a music player with PyQt4 and Phonon. The player works well for most of my music, but some MP3 files won't work.

I tried with a lot of MP3s, approximately 1 out of 10 seems to have the problem. Phonon doesn't send any error, it simply doesn't play the song. Just to be sure, I compared two songs, one working and the other not, and they use the same codec (MPEG-1 Layer 3), both are in 44100Hz and 320 kb/s, tags are in ID3v2.3, neither use any special characters in their tags or filepath, and both work correctly when I play them in WMP.

I initialize the player with :

```
self.player = Phonon.createPlayer(Phonon.MusicCategory)
```

then to launch a song, I use :

```
self.player.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(path_to_file))
self.player.play()
```

Obviously, there must be some difference between the files, maybe in the way they were encoded (the whole album of a non-working song won't work either), but I have no clue why some files are ok and other not... Do you have an idea of what could cause the problem ?

### EDIT :

I'm on Windows 10, running PyQt 4.11.4 and Python 2.7.15. Not sure about the Phonon version though... :-/

I think I found something though... I managed to get an error for incorrect MP3s :

> "Contacts could not be connected because they do not support the same transport. (0x80040266)."

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560349/direct-show-9-phonon-error-pins-cannot-connect), it's caused by the file metadata, and when I did some tests, it looks like it comes from the album cover's file size. When the size is higher than ~108 KB, the MP3 doesn't work, but if I resize the image so that it's below this limit, the MP3 works...

Here's a simplified code to test with a [problematic mp3](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/19b871e2f4f1db930f065ca44639eb7120190204001109/c18186aecbb62e76122d3bef7957eb9620190204001109/f1d817) :

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.phonon import *

class MusicPlayer(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.player = Phonon.createPlayer(Phonon.MusicCategory)

        BTN_play = QPushButton("Play")
        BTN_play.pressed.connect(self.play)
        self.setCentralWidget(BTN_play)

        self.show()

    def play(self):
        path = "path/to/file.mp3"
        self.player.setCurrentSource(Phonon.MediaSource(path))
        self.player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MusicPlayer()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Still, I'd prefer not to edit each file metadata to correct it. Could there be a way to make Phonon ignore the cover image when parsing a file so that it doesn't make an error ?

Comment: Have you tried using pyqt5 with [QMediaPlayer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html)? Official support for both qt4 and phonon was dropped a long time ago, so issues like this will never be fixed. And why are you still using python2?

Comment: I'm still on Python 2 and PyQt4 because it's what we use at my workplace for retro-compatibility reasons, and it's a bit of a headache having to switch habits when I come home. Seemed simpler to keep the same config in both places. Still, I'll check with PyQt5, it might indeed be a bug that was fixed in newer versions.